# How do I add a widget to the header area of the 'Twenty Fourteen' WP theme?

Tags: wordpress, web-development, website-design, theme

I would like to add a widget to the header area (above the main menu) of the WordPress Twenty Fourteen theme. Ideally this would cut down the size of the header image from the full width to half, with the other half of the area holding the new widget.

I am not well versed in php, css, java, or any other useful stuff like that, so the more simple the solution, the better.

I've not been able to locate a plug-in which achieves this outcome, but a plugin would certainly be my preferred way of doing this, as I can then easily do it across multiple sites if required.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: @Shanodin you'd first create a child theme and move the header.php in to the child theme folder. Create a new functions file and register a new sidebar area. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar then call `dynamic_sidebar` to load it in the header. Widgets go into sidebar areas. Split the logo and right side widget area (sidebar) in two 50% columns to keep the theme responsive. I can help you out it'll only take a few minutes http://bit.ly/1yVO6Zq

Answer (score 1):

The "Twenty Fourteen" theme does not support header widgets.  Plugins don't usually modify themes, either.   Your options are:

- Find a theme that has the feature you want
- Edit your theme

Your theme can be edited from "Admin" -> "Appearance" -> "Editor" -> "header.php".  There you could add the code for calling the widget you want.

A word of caution, though:  If you do edit your theme, your changes will get overwritten if you install updates to your theme.  The default "Twenty Fourteen" theme does get updated occasionally and you would have to be careful not to install these updates.  It appears that creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) would be a way of preventing your customizations from being overridden.

Comment: What would the code be to call a text widget? And would using a child theme resolve the issues with possibly being overwtitten?

Comment: Yes, it appears that a child theme would be appropriate.  I'm not familiar enough with WordPress to be able to answer the question about what code to call.  I'd suggest asking at the [WordPress deveopment StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).